# Firebase storage not connecting anymore, inside thread block

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an android app and I want to be able to retrieve the local author username in order to have a unique identifier of every user (users can upload their profile picture and I want to be able to retrieve them), but ever since I had to put those **runOnDbThread** brackets, it forces me to put **author** inside a try-catch which becomes only a local variable, so I have to put the entire firebase upload method **uploadimage2** inside that thread. If I take off **runOnUiThreadUnlessDestroyed** brackets, then my app crashes, but when I put it, it doesn't crash but only tells me that firebase can't connect: `E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: etc.` .Anyone has any idea how to make firebase connect?

```
public void uploadImage(View view) throws DbException {
    runOnDbThread(() -> {
        LocalAuthor author;
        String nickname;
        // Load the local pseudonym
        try {
            author = identityManager.getLocalAuthor();
            nickname = author.getName();
            uploadImage2(nickname,author);
        } catch (DbException e) {
            return;
        }

    });
}

public void uploadImage2(String nickname, Author author){
    runOnUiThreadUnlessDestroyed(() -> {

        //create reference to images folder and assing a name to the file that will be uploaded
        imageRef = storageRef.child(nickname + "/" + selectedImage.getLastPathSegment());
        //creating and showing progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        //starting upload
        uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(selectedImage);
        // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
        uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                //sets and increments value of progressbar
                progressDialog.incrementProgressBy((int) progress);
            }
        });

        // Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                Toast.makeText(AvatarActivity.this,"Error in uploading!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Toast.makeText(AvatarActivity.this,"Upload successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                //showing the uploaded image in ImageView using the download url
                Picasso.with(AvatarActivity.this).load(downloadUrl).into(imageView);
            }
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain what `runOnDbThread` and `runOnUiThreadUnlessDestroyed` actually do?  They are not standard Android things.

Comment: Also consider that you can use class member fields to share data across everything in that class.

Comment: runondbthread is from my open-source project...gives me an error         java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()....so I checked other solutions and they said to run on a UI thread

Comment: I just want to use that author variable outside the thread

Comment: Threading doesn't matter to class member fields.

Comment: how I can use class member fields?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: IT WORKED! Using static worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per Doug Stevenson, using the nickname String as a static variable and fetching the variable from a getter method worked! No need to work around those annoying threads